# Python. Создание класса-списка, реализованный на основе массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

День добрый. Я в ооп на Python довольно не продолжительное время нахожусь(если можно так выразиться), и в связи с учебой этому ремеслу появился вопрос. Возможно ли создать класс-список, реализованный на основе массива? Этот класс-список принимает экземпляры других классов, а методы, которые находятся в этом классе - это те же методы, что и у структуры данных на Python(списка). Прошу помощи

```
class ClassList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list

    def append(self, ob):
        self.list.append(ob)

a = input("Введите данные: ").split(', ')
car = Car(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6])
array = ClassList()
array.append(car)
array.append(car_copy)

print(array.__str__())
```

А это то, что получается на выходе, хотя метод **str** класса Car переопределен

```
[<classes.ChildClass_1.Car object at 0x03DA9E30>, 
<classes.ChildClass_1.Car object at 0x03DCE610>]
```

Comment: А что список это не массив?

Comment: Вы покажите как вы пытаетесь реализовать задуманное,  может всё гораздо проще чем вы думаете

Comment: Добавьте ваш класс Car

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли создать класс-список, реализованный на основе массива?

да, возможно.

> Этот класс-список принимает экземпляры других классов,

тут понятно, что будут проблемы. Если вы решили действительно (например -  в учебных целях) реализовывать список на массиве - то массив по определению "последовательность однотипных элементов". Соответственно, экземпляр произвольного (или тем более - разных) классов вы в такой список непосредственно не засунете.

Однако, если вы допускаете возможность работать с массивом указателей, каждый из которых будет указывать на свой объект-экземпляр "другого класса" - то так вполне можно. Более того, в Python список реализован именно по подобной схеме, а не как классический список.

> а методы, которые находятся в этом классе - это те же методы, что и у
>   структуры данных на Python(списка).

Ну, какие методы реализуете самостоятельно - такие будут. Хоть те же, хоть подобные, хоть какие-то специфические (если надо).